# Parsing an IP ADDR in a attribute that will use in a configration

Tags: templates, chef-infra

I have a set up of a master and slave postgresql server. I need my dbslave server to see my dbmaster server. So in my `pg_hba.conf` I have a ruby variable name `private_ip` within a node.

The template `pg_hba.conf` looks like this:

```
 <% node["postgresql"]["pg_hba"].each do |hba| %>
 <%= hba['type'] %> <%= hba['db'] %> <%= hba['user'] %> <%= hba['addr'] %> <%= hba['method'] %>
 <% end %>
```

And in recipe it look like this. It will get the value of each hash to the node.

`slave.rb` recipe:

```
 # hba
 node.override["postgresql"]["pg_hba"] = [ { "type" => "host", "db" => "all", "user" =>"all", "addr" => "<%= private_ip %>", "method" => "trust"}
```

To get the ip address I use the search method.

```
 dbserver = search(:node, "role:pg_server_master")
 private_ip = "#{dbserver[0][:private_ip]}"
 puts private_ip
```

The question now is - how can I put the value of the result of the search on the node.override variable `<%= private_ip =>`.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the search method from chef:

```
  # getting the private ip for pg_hba.conf
  dbserver = search(:node, "role:oftheserver")
  private_ip = dbserver[0]['ipaddress']
  mask = @ipaddress.to_s + "/32"
```

So the output of this search will be x.x.x.x/32 in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Pass necessary variables to the template:

```
template "/etc/whatever/pg_hba.conf" do
  source "pg_hba.conf.erb"
  mode 0644
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  variables({
    :private_ip => private_ip
  })
end
```

And then use it in template:

```
<%= @private_ip =>
```

Comment: Im my recipe i used the search method from chef. Just like below: